# RESTful API clarifications

Tags: restful-architecture

I've building a new RESTful API and was looking for clarification. It is ok to use POST to update and PUT to create?

Also, if I try to create an item that can only have one instance in my id (think a list of types), what would my http error code be? 409?

Comment: see http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html and yes 409 is fine

Comment: I read that, so are you saying POST to update and PUT to create is not a good idea?

Comment: correct, you should use `POST` to create and `PUT` to update. If you really want to be precise, you should use `PUT` to replace an entire object and `PATCH` to update attributes of an object but most people just use `PUT` for both

Comment: PUT is perfectly legitimate for creating a resource when the client knows the unique ID that the resource will be given. POST is used when the unique ID is server-assigned. POST may also be used for other calls beyond just creating resources, as outlined in RFC 7231.